# ¿Por qué los atributos añadidos mediante el método addAttribute de la interfaz Model se pueden acceder dentro de un archivo jsp?

Tags: spring-mvc

En el método de un controlador que recibe como argumento un objeto Model se añade al modelo un atributo como se muestra a continuación:

```
@RequestMapping("/proceso")
public String añadirAtributo(Model modelo) {
    String mensaje="atributo nuevo";
            
    modelo.addAttribute("nuevoAtributo", mensaje);
    
    return "mostrarAtributo";
}
```

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo en el archivo *mostrarAtributo.jsp* puedo acceder al atributo *nuevoAtributo* mediante `${nuevoAtributo}` si en este archivo no se ha declarado dicho atributo? ¿Por qué está disponible en ese ámbito?

Comment: Porque así funciona Spring MVC: la instancia de model que recibes ahí también la recibe la clase generada por tu JSP, es la manera de comunicarse con ella. Para más detalles, mira la documentación de Spring